Limit Green Gradient and start showing white
I'm trying to limit the gradient green colour from the screen and then show the white colour to the rest of the screen. But my green gradient is almost filling up the entire screen.

What I want is to limit the green to the center and then start showing the white:

Here's my code for the gradient_green_background.xml:
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Top gradient -->
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#3ACF96"
                android:endColor="@color/forest_green"
                android:angle="180"
                android:type="linear" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="0dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#ffffff"
                android:endColor="#00ffffff"
                android:angle="90"
                android:type="linear" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>

Thank you so much! The background is set within the relativelayout with match parent height.

As per OP's answer, this has been answered here: How can I limit the gradient in Android Studio?

Considering you're also using a white gradient, you can for instance act on this and using a centerColor and a centerY attributes, something like this:
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Top gradient -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#3ACF96"
                android:endColor="@color/forest_green"
                android:angle="180"
                android:type="linear" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="0dp" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#ffffff"
                android:centerColor="#80ffffff"
                android:centerY="0.9"
                android:endColor="#00ffffff"
                android:angle="90"
                android:type="linear" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>

You should tune these 2 new attributes according to your needs. For instance a centerY of 0.9 means that the centerColor is placed well above the center of the shape.

Thanks for your answer. I'll try this one later and update you.
